# mysql USE CASE STATEMENT as variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query with a quite large:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(added_on) 'Week Of', 
    COUNT(*) 'No. Updates', 
    (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) <= 500 THEN 6.75 WHEN COUNT(*) <= 750 
      THEN 6.30 WHEN COUNT(*) <= 1000 THEN 6.00 WHEN COUNT(*) <= 1250 
      THEN 5.50 ELSE 4.60 END
     ) Rate
    Rate * COUNT(*) // HOW TO DO THIS??
FROM
     Fox_title
GROUP BY
    WEEK(added_on)
ORDER BY
    added_on
```

How would I multiple the `COUNT(*)` * the `Rate` that I have from my `CASE` statement? Or do I have to write that CASE statement again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either repeat the `case` or use a subquery:

```
select t.*, t.Rate * `No. Updates`
from (SELECT DATE(min(added_on)) as `Week Of`, COUNT(*) as `No. Updates`, 
             (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) <= 500 THEN 6.75
                   WHEN COUNT(*) <= 750 THEN 6.30
                   WHEN COUNT(*) <= 1000 THEN 6.00
                   WHEN COUNT(*) <= 1250 THEN 5.50
                   ELSE 4.60
              END) as Rate
      FROM Fox_title
      GROUP BY WEEK(added_on)
     ) t
ORDER BY `Week Of`;
```

I made a few other changes to your query.  First, I changed the single quotes around the column aliases to back ticks.  Single quotes should be used, in general, only for string constants.  Back ticks are the MySQL method for enclosing identifiers.

I also changed `date(addon)` to `date(min(addon))`.  This ensures that you will get the earliest date in the week.  Otherwise, you get an arbitrary date.

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't using the CASE statement two times provide much better performance than using a subquery?

Comment: Using the `case` statement twice would have better performance.  However, because this is a `group by` query, MySQL is already writing and reading the data multiple times for the aggregation.  The additional materialization of the subquery might have a minimal effect on performance.  But, in general, you are correct for MySQL.